# String split using php and regEx

Tags: php, regex

How to get string by trimming * at start (if present)and end (if present)of given string usig Reg Exp in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you need regex? PHP's `trim()` function allows you to specify a character list to trim from either side:

```
$stripAsterisks = trim($string, '*');
```

http://php.net/trim

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function .. ?

Comment: I would like to get match with *

Comment: If you read the trim documentation, you'll see that it is possible to specify the character you want trimmed. For example, '*'.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use regex (which I wouldn't (use trim)) you could try:

```
$result = preg_replace('/^\*+|\*+$/', '', '***foo bar***');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need regular expressions in this case and if there is alternative you should avoid regular expressions (they're a slower in flavour of other functions.
I think this will solve your problem:

```
$trimmedData = trim($string, '*');
```